# How to use functionality of do while in python

Tags: python-2.7

Here is a simple progarm to tell whether a year is leap or not.

```
year = input("Enter a year: ")

if year % 4 != 0:
    print"\nNot leap year!"

else:
    if year % 100 != 0:
        print"\nLeap year"
    else:
        if year % 400 == 0:
           print"\nLeap year"
         else:
             print"\nNot leap year"
```

I want to prompt user "Do you want to continue..(y/n)" then he will enter choice and loop will iterate again but not able to do that.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Use a `while` loop :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common way to emulate do-while:

```
while True:
    # body
    if condition:
       break
```